# Are bounded subsets of Lie groups totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $ G $ be a finite dimensional real Lie group, and take a bounded ball $ B_R(e) \subset G $ in it, coming from the Riemannian metric, which itself is induced from an inner product on $ \mathfrak{g} = \text{Lie}(G) $.

I want to show, that such balls are totally bounded. For small $ R $, this is trivial, because $ G $ is locally compact. For general $ R $ it seemed to be true to me, but I did not find an answer to it. I had trouble to work with the dimension of $ G $. What I mean with this: In $ \mathbb{R}^n $ we need (about) $ (R/ \epsilon)^{\dim(G)} $-many $ (-\epsilon, \epsilon)^{\dim(G)} $-boxes to cover $ B_R(e) $. I wasn't able to carry this argument over to the Lie group $ G $.

Am I overseeing something easy? Or is it not even true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the expected positive answer, but with an overkill argument. The generalized Hopf-Rinow theorem applies here, which states, that if a length space is complete and locally compact (which all three are satisfied by a Lie group $ G $), then the space is in particular proper, i.e. closed and bounded sets are compact. See for example:

https://www.math.ethz.ch/~lang/LengthSpaces.pdf

But there must be a shorter and nicer argument; anybody an idea?

Comment: I actually believe that this is close to an optimal *direct* proof and I wouldn't go so far as to call it overkill. The diagonalization process used in the linked notes is the usual way of establishing compactness in metric spaces and minor technicalities aside, it is really quite similar to the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem. That a Lie group satisfies the requirements is clear. Of course it would be nice(r) to have a short proof *using* the Heine-Borel theorem...

Comment: Oke, I had a look on the argument and you're right, it is not that involved. I have to admit, I just needed a positive answer, and did not have a closer look on the argument. But I really appreciate that you posted a comment, thanks.